# angular 5 ViewChild clientHeight, scrollTop, scrollHeight are all zero after

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, angularjs-directive

I have a component With scrollable content.
However when I try to get the dimension of the scrollable content in angular using the ViewChild I get zero for all values, however if I use jQuery to grab the element I get the correct values. Why is this happening? How should I get the correct dimensions in Angular? I verified both have the same element, but I believe angular not have the correct values or element perhaps? Looking in the console both jQuery and Angular seem to have the same element judging by the css classes and html name..

template:

```
<div class="container-fluid px-5 py-5 scrolled-contents" style="display:inline-block" #scrolledContents>

  <div class="row">
  ...content
  </div>
</div>
```

controller code:

```
export class ScrollContainer implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('scrolledContents') private scrollContainer: ElementRef;

  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onScroll(): void {
    const jQueryelement = $(".scrolled-contents")[0];
    const angularElement = this.scrollContainer.nativeElement;
    // angularElement.clientHeight == 0, angularElement.offsetHeight == 0, angularElement.scrollTop == 0, etc
    // jQueryElement.clientHeight == correctValue, jQueryElement.offsetHeight == correct value, jQueryElement.scrollTop == correctValue 
  }
```

Please help ?

Comment: I want to deal with your problem. Would you share something like "Plunker"?

Comment: hmm I think it might be hard to include a plunker, I'm not sure..I can try .

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-qvjnwa?file=app/app.component.ts), I can't seem to reproduce your issue.

Did you give your whole code ? Is it a routed component ? Any information would be useful.

Comment: Seems you're using angular 4.4.3, I'm using Angular 5, with boostrap 4.0, and the element is a boostrap container, can you try to reproduce with angular 5? also my container doesn't have a specific height specified on th element.

Comment: In addition the content I create inside it is other components (not that should effect it). the content is created after the page is loaded of course.

Comment: It doesn't rely on Angular version but anyway, just made it to 5, same URL, you can check. And if you didn't screw up your CSS properties, the content should not be an issue.

Comment: @DoryZidon does "scroll" appear when "row" have overflow? If it happens `window:scroll` doesn't work in your case.

Comment: Are you sure the update worked? I'm getting errors about missing rx files.. Can you double check or send a new link ?

Comment: Yes it worked, just edit the code (put a space, erase and rewrite a character ...) to make the app bundle

Comment: @trichetriche Look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-tpepfa?file=app/app.component.html) . In your case if overflow in inline doesn't work.

Comment: Well of course, you're not scrolling the host, you're scrolling one of its children. [See this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-vkgcen?file=app/app.component.ts) to know how to listen to child events

Comment: Oh well, good luck ! Just remember to [take a look at this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-vkgcen?file=app/app.component.ts) to know how to listen to your ViewChild events

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-5goufv I have updated, and now the scrollTop or height do not change..

Comment: @trichetriche render is deprecated..So you think I should try the renderv2 path ?

Comment: Exact same thing yes, just change your import to Renderer2. I'm looking at your blitz and will edit it to assist you

Comment: @trichetriche thanks man, appreciate your help :) I'm trying it now..I'm not sure why all my values are zero there.

Comment: Instead of trying to get your element scroll, try using the document with `document.documentElement.scrollTop` (if it suits your needs of course) and [see how it works well here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-zbbvta?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks the prolbem that scrollTop for document seems like much less than the clientHeight of the element, not sure how that happens? Try and see buddy..

Comment: The scroll on the element doesn't get called either, with the renderer I suspect we aren't scrolling the element but the document, which is great, but the question is why is the height so strnage.

Comment: The scroll height is lesser than your element height because it returns the position of the scrollbar on the right, not the height of your element. And yes, we aren't scrolling the child of your component, we're scrolling the component. I suspect the host binding doesn't work because of stackblitz, maybe you should try it on your own computer, here we are working in an iframe, this isn't the best solution ...

Comment: Seems so whatever I do will end up being sort of the answer, do you agree @trichetriche ? Seems I cannot be super accurate here, as I cannot seem to get the scroll top for the element only the document?

Comment: Those are the ways of getting your elements positions and scrol values. I agree this is sort of an answer, but since it is **not** an answer, I think you should try and see on your own project until you figure it out. This is what I would do, even though yes, it might take a while

Comment: The only errors are import errors and they're not dependant on me, they're dependant of the version used in the blitz. Simply importing the whole rxjs library corrects all of the errors. But sure, go ahead, "report" it, I'm sure it will make a difference on an old and closed question.

Comment: Oh and by the way, if you had make the effort to read the comments, you would have seen that simply updating the blitz would make it work.